# Where should I ask question related to indoor farming

Tags: discussion, support, bug

As a project, a bit of fun and experiment, I want to work on 'Indoor farming', but with great projects come great questions. So did I, mostly with light frequency, intensity, watt, stuff that you can't google. Since there is no specific SE regarding it, I am confused about where to ask my doubts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions about "light frequency, intensity, watt," issues of indoor farming can be asked in Biology SE and Sustainability SE I think. Here's one for example, you can search each site for more: [Are two colors (red + blue) necessary for LED grow lights, or would either color be sufficient?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/58572/27918)

There are some space farming questions here in Space SE:

- [Which is easier to build on mars per square kilometer; greenhouse windows or photovoltaics/LEDs?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22017/12102)
- [Are there any existing technologies, or research, that investigate the sustainable production of food for manned exploration trips?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/368/12102)
- [Power to grow food per person](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22012/12102)
- [Cubic meters of martian greenhouse required](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26945/12102)
- [Manufacturing rope, textile, and clothing on Mars](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25381/12102)
- [Mars Watershield Greenhouse Question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26377/12102)
- [Using bamboo as space construction material](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23703/12102)
- [How does this spinach-growing Mars lander design work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30020/12102)
- [Sunroofs on Mars - durable transparent structural plastics lighter than glass to ship from Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22031/12102)

Comment: Uhoh, you are awesome man. You just solve my whole problem. Thanks a lot, buddy.

Comment: Did you grow the plants using LED then?

Comment: @Gurkirat I have lots of experience asking questions in Stack Exchange, but not so much growing plants. :-)

Comment: The question in the SE was asked by you, so I thought, maybe you were creating an indoor farm.

Comment: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58572/are-two-colors-red-blue-necessary-for-led-grow-lights-or-would-either-color?newreg=235d6c67bfde4262be37966cc77b6d43

I am not able to access ashpublication experiments. It opens a menu, which results in dead end. Did you bookmark links?

Comment: @Gurkirat photos in articles linked in the [2nd question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22017/12102) and what can be seen in "grow light" displays show the weird purple color often used to grow plants indoors. It's a mixture of red and blue light. I've always wondered why a short and a long wavelength were both included in grow lights, so I asked the biology SE question. I don't know what "ashpublication experiments" means or where you are seeing it, can you be more specific? Oh also just fixed link https://dyna-gro.com/the-difference-between-chlorophyll-a-b-and-photosynthesis-overview/

Comment: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58572/are-two-colors-red-blue-necessary-for-led-grow-lights-or-would-either-color?newreg=235d6c67bfde4262be37966cc77b6d43
In this question look at the links in answer posted by "resonating"

Comment: @Gurkirat when you want to share a link to a question or one of the answers, you can use the "share" feature https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkU4H.png Ya those links have rotted. I shouldn't have accepted the answer with so little information in the answer post itself. I left a comment for the author, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: And thank you for the tips. It's more convenient now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Gardening StackExchange](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/), and it has a tag called [indoors](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indoors) with over 600 questions.  Also has questions about grow lamps and lighting.

Just make sure you grow arugula, also known as [rocket](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rocket).  (Fun fact: Marco Polo named the Chinese invention "rocket" because it was shaped like an arugula leaf.)

Comment: haha... For sure Dr Cooper. Thank you for your answer. And yes, it was a fun fact.